# Resharper Code Inspection bug?

Tags: vb.net, resharper

Example:

```
Public Enum Vehicles As Integer
    Car = 0
    MotorBike = 1
    Plane = 2
End Enum
```

To get each vehicle member value (`0`, `1`, `2`) I suppose I have to cast it like this:

```
DirectCast(Vehicles.Car, Integer)
```

It works fine, however, Resharper produces this warning on intellisense:

> "Cannot cast expression of type Vehicles to type Integer"

Why is that? Is this a bug? Is there another way for me to get the value of each member without converting? (Cint, etc...)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, convention dictates that your enumeration be named `Vehicle`, i.e. singular, rather than `Vehicles`, i.e. plural.  You should only use a plural name for an enumeration if you use powers of 2 for the values and apply the `Flags` attribute, thus allowing a variable of that type to store multiple values simultaneously, e.g.

```
<Flags>
Public Enum Vehicles As Integer
    Car = 1
    MotorBike = 2
    Plane = 4
End Enum
```

Obviously that is in appropriate in this particular case but there are many enumerations declared that way.

As for the question, it is presumably a bug in ReSharper because the VB code compiles and runs without issue.  My guess is that, when `DirectCast` is used, ReSharper looks for a direct inheritance or implementation relationship, which it won't find in the case of enumerations and integral types.  If you use `CInt` instead then you won't get that warning because `CInt` doesn't require such a relationship.

Comment: I don't need the flags attribute in this case, but that power of two thing, i never thought of that ;)
I prefer using DirectCast tho, keeps me from making any mistakes at compile-time, and using the correct types, since CInt will try to convert almost everything to integer...

I just wanted to check and share this "bug", maybe it will be fixed in a future version, or maybe the current one since i got the older (8.2).
Thanks for the explanation, for now, i believe i'll turn off Code Inspection for this case.

Comment: I'm using R#9 and I see the same behaviour.  If you've found an issue then you should report it to JetBrains so that they can fix it.  I checked and a cast works fine in C#.

Comment: You would only ever use powers of 2 if you want a single variable to be able to store multiple values simultaneously and if you want that then you should apply the `Flags` attribute.  They go hand in hand.

Comment: @jmcihinney I was going to post a new issue on there, but it's already there for over a month. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-427447

Comment: Unfortunately for VB developers, R#'s pedigree as a C# tool still shows, with the VB functionality still lagging.  The gap is closing though, which is a good sign.